# How can I join the frequency of repeated categories to a 'groupby' in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, mean, frequency

[UPDADE]
I am dealing with a large dateset, and now I have reached this part:

```
agg_diag = ('mean', 'median', 'count')
columns_names_diag = ['ae_diag_mean','ae_diag_median']
df[columns_names_diag].groupby(df['Code']).agg(agg_diag)
```

Being the output

```
       ae_diag_mean         ae_diag_median         
       mean median count    mean median count   
Code                                    
04189  82.0  82.0    1      82.0  82.0  1       
07811  14.0  14.0    1      14.0  14.0  1       
07812  3.0   3.0     1      3.0   3.0   1      
0794   0.0   0.0     2      0.0   0.0   2       
0914   4.0   4.0     1      4.0   4.0   1
```

However, since that "count" is a repetition in both columns in this dataframe, I just want to have one column for it. Count is the quantity of each code that exists in this dataset. So I want an output like this:

```
       ae_diag_mean  ae_diag_median        
       mean median   mean median       count    
Code                                    
04189  82.0  82.0    82.0  82.0          1      
07811  14.0  14.0    14.0  14.0          1      
07812  3.0   3.0     3.0   3.0           1     
0794   0.0   0.0     0.0   0.0           2      
0914   4.0   4.0     4.0   4.0           1
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The data you've provided are not a complete copy-pastable example. But it sounds like you're looking for `groupby('Code').size()`

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler I updated the question, maybe you can understand better what I meant. It's because I can add just one column for count

Comment: Could you post starting data as well as the expected output? Readers still have nothing to test on right now. In the meantime, you could try two steps: first, run your current code, but without aggregating by `'count'`. After that, run `df['count'] = df[columns_names_diag].groupby('Code').count()`